# How do I make Tor use IPv6 for connecting to other peers?

Tags: configuration, ipv6

Even if I put the following, it still only makes [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) connections to the outside world:

```
ORPort [::]:9001 IPv6Only
OutboundBindAddress [::]
Bridge [<an IPv6 of a tor node of mine>]:9001
ClientUseIPv6 1
ClientPreferIPv6ORPort 1
```

I'm using tor-0.2.4.17rc.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hmm, "Bridge []:9001" doesn't look like a valid config option.  Do you use bridges for your attempt or not?

Answer (score 7):

There's only about 70 relays with an IPv6 address. So you should probably connect over IPv6 about one time out of sixty. But that's only if you don't use entry guards (you do use entry guards by default).

There is currently no client configuration option for not using IPv4. Also, if there was one, using that would sadly fail at the moment (see  https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6027).

Answer (score 1):

I know that IPv6 works when using bridges.

This is my minimal torrc:

```
UseBridges 1
Bridge [<some ipv6 address>]:443
Log info stdout
```

When started with this torrc, my Tor only has connections to my bridge over IPv6.

I don't know if using a Tor client without bridges actually works with just IPv6 yet.  If I find out I'll update this answer accordingly.

Comment: I was wanting to have my roaming laptop connect to some other tor relays
as bridges directly instead of to the global network since I can encrypt
the traffic over OpenVPN and hide what I am doing and/or not make a
house I visit be marked as a tor site just because I exited traffic that
heads to tor nodes.

Bottom line is:

 server = 'ORPort' and optionally 'BridgeRelay'
 client = 'UseBridegs 1' and must not have 'ORPort' nor 'BridgeRelay' enabled

Perhaps someone can adjust the tor manual pages around UseBridges accordingly?

Comment: @todd, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  But if you think we could improve the manpage, please file a bug on https://bugs.torproject.org/ describing what you would like to change and why.  (Patches give brownie points, but aren't required.)

Answer (score 0):

2023 IPv6 works fine. Here is [IPv6 tor roadmap](https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/wikis/org/roadmaps/Tor/IPv6)

It's enouth to have this lines in torrc

```
ClientUseIPv6 1
ClientUseIPv4 0
```

to connect through IPv6